# Would React be suitable for building a chat site like Slack or Hipchat?

Tags: reactjs

I've recently started learning React and don't know enough to make a judgement on whether it would be a good library to use for a chat web app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HipChat *is* built with React: https://developer.atlassian.com/blog/2015/02/rebuilding-hipchat-with-react/

I believe it also uses [Material-UI](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/app-bar) since some of the components are near identical (buttons, icon/label placement, etc.)

Comment: well would you look at that, React all the way